# Why is the result of a subclass of datetime minus timedelta a datetime object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I've the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class MyDate(datetime):
      pass

d = MyDate.now()
t = timedelta(1, 1, 1)
print type(d)
print type(d - t)
```

The output is the following:

```
<class '__main__.MyDate'>
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

So now to my question, why does a subclass minus `timedelta` result in the super class?

In addition is there a workaround for this where I don't have to encapsulate a `datetime` object and redirect all methods of `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MyDate` sub-class doesn't override the subtraction function `__sub__()`, so inherits the function from the base class, which returns an instance of the base class.

A workaround for what? What are you trying to achieve by sub-classing `datetime`?

Comment: I'm doing the following `class Date(datetime.datetime, JSONSerialize)` so I have an interface for JSON serialization and in addition I want to use pytz to work with timezones. But pytz uses timedelta to correct the timestamp and then I lose my interface, when I convert from one TZ to another. So I was looking for a solution where I don't have to write 10 wrapper methods for datetime.

Comment: I don't see a way around wrapping at least `__add__` and `__sub__` if you want to manipulate your subclass with `timedelta` objects